# Mat and written image are not same

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I create a `Mat` variable in my program, but when I pass it directly to a function, it has different manner compare to when I write it with `imwrite` and again read it in function with `imread`.

Why this is happening?
The correct form for me is when I write and read the image, but in this case program have to access to hard 2 times and it makes the program slow.
How I can prevent it and use my `Mat` variable directly?

Comment: are you using some lossy compression, when writing it ( e.g. jpg ) ?

Comment: *why* are you writing to disk ?

Comment: can you explain what kind of different manner appears? Maybe you achieve what you want if you first copy your matrix: `cv::Mat newMat; yourMat.copyTo(newMat); functioCall(newMat);

Comment: @berak: yes. I'm using .jpg and test .png. But surprisingly, this lossy compression works better; and I don't know why!

Comment: @Micka: I use this image in a image processing algorithm and want to detect some objects. when I pass the Mat, my algorithm doesn't work!

Comment: @ayssa so your question is not why written and read images are not the same, but what happens during writing, or why your algorithm works better after lossy compression? Maybe your algorithm has problems with noise, try to filter your image with a small gaussian filter before calling your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to view your Image using any other application, you could write your Mat object onto an XML/YAML class using OpenCV's built in [FileStorage](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/core/file_input_output_with_xml_yml/file_input_output_with_xml_yml.html) Implementation. Following is a sample :-

```
//Writing
cv::FileStorage fs;
fs.open(filename, cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
fs<<"MyImage"<<Image1;

//Reading
fs.open(filename, cv::FileStorage::READ);
fs["MyImage"]>>Image1;

fs.release(); //Very Important
```